# How to count error messages in nlog from code

Tags: .net, nlog

I'm using NLog lib for logging in my app. There is a task to count from code error and fatal messages in log-file. Is there build-in methods for it? I tried to apply `{$counter}`, but I couldn't use it only for error and fatal messages without printing to log-file.

Comment: Count since when? Application start? And when and where should the count be printed?

Comment: Yes, since application start. I'm replacing the current logging approach in app to NLog. It has ErrorCount property. The property value isn't printed to file. It's used in autotests and theoretically can be passed to another application that collects statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curious what the number should be used for, but one way could be the `MethodCall`-target:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <target name="m" xsi:type="MethodCall" className="SomeNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly" methodName="LogMethod">
        <parameter layout="${level}" />
    </target>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="m" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

And then the following code in "MyAssembly"-project:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    using System;

    public class MyClass
    {
        static int ErrorCounter;

        public static void LogMethod(string level)
        {
            if (level == LogLevel.Error.ToString())
               ++ErrorCounter;
        }
    }
}
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MethodCall-target

Comment: Many thanks! I think it'll be suitable for my task.